# what is the difference between following.... Is the difference is same for both c & java?

Tags: java

what is the difference between....  Is the difference is same for both c & java??

```
  static int a=10;
  //&
  static int a;
  a=10;
  // Is the difference is same for both c & java??
```

Comment: The second example doesn't compile in Java. What sort of difference are you looking for?

Comment: Why would you use variant 2 if you can use variant 1? The first example would be way more readable and the second wouldn't be usable in the form you've provided. If you can't use variant 1 we need more information on the why.

Comment: `static` means something a bit different in Java from what it means in C.  It's not really clear what you're asking here.

Comment: i have read somewhere static variable hold latest value in java..Is that applicable for both c also?

Comment: also the above 2 statements may have different meaning in java.

Comment: for example static int a=10; //a is considered as static variable here but  static int a; a=10; //here 1st line  declares 'a' as static variable & i think it assigns default value 0 to it....so is that true?

Answer (score 0):

`static int a;` declares a variable, `a=10;` defines it. You can combine both to make the code shorter but if you don't know the value `a` should have during programming time (for example because it should be a user input value), you need to use the second method and define `a` later in some other method.

Keep in mind that the second example only works if `a=10` is inside some kind of method, otherwise you will get a compiler error.

In c, undefined variables will basically have undefined values (if I remember correctly), in java, undefined int variables will have the value 0. So in c you might run into troubles when you try to use it before you define it, in java... well... you'll still have a value of 0 but it usually doesn't cause the same amount of trouble it would in c.

---

Example (see comments):

```
public class ExampleClass 
{
    public static int a = 10;
    public int b = 5;
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ExampleClass exampleInstanceOne = new ExampleClass();
        ExampleClass exampleInstanceTwo = new ExampleClass();
        exampleInstanceOne.a = 20;
        exampleInstanceOne.b = 20;
        exampleInstanceTwo.a = 50;
        exampleInstanceTwo.b = 50;

        System.out.println("First a: " + exampleInstanceOne.a);
        System.out.println("First b: " + exampleInstanceOne.b);
        System.out.println("Second a: " + exampleInstanceTwo.a);
        System.out.println("Second b: " + exampleInstanceTwo.b);
    }
}
```

Result will be:

```
First a: 50
First b: 20
Second a: 50
Second b: 50
```

The difference is that each object had his own copy of b, so we get two different values, but since a was static, they both share the value of a, so if we change it for the second object, it will also be changed for the first one.

Comment: i don't get it..what you have explained..please keep it simple.

Comment: i thought I did :D

Comment: i have read somewhere static variable hold latest value in java..Is that applicable for both c also?

Comment: every variable in every programming language I know always holds the latest value it is assigned (even if it's not static). If it didn't, it would be a really pointless construct. static makes sure the variable will only exist ONCE, no matter how many objects of a class containing a static variable you create and use. So all instances will share the same variable (instead of each having their own copy).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between those 2 lines, 2nd one is for readability. But when you are hardcoding values its a dumb rule to follow readability.

All that matters is where you are writing these lines. If you are not writing the line : a=10; in a static block or method, you will face compilation error. Refer the image below.
[You could see compile-time error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1EDG.png)